# js get chain of constructor names

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I generate a chain of constructor names based on inheritance:

```
class Person {
}

class User extends Person {
}

$userClassIdentifier = generateIdentifier(User.constructor)     
// userClassIdentifier = 'Person.User'

function generateIdentifier(constructor) {
        if (constructor.prototype && constructor.prototype.__proto__
            && constructor.prototype.__proto__.constructor && constructor.prototype.__proto__.constructor.name) {
            return  `${constructor.prototype.__proto__.constructor.name}.${constructor.name}`
        }
        return constructor.name
}
```

this works for one level of inheritance. But it seems very hacky/ugly. Is there a nicer way to do it and to make it work for an unknown number of levels deep?

Comment: What's your goal behind this ?

Comment: ^^ e.g., what end result are you looking for?

Comment: I have to pass an identifier through a webrequest that can later be used on the server to create an instance of the exact same class

Comment: @T.J.Crowder If I have SUV extending Car extending Vehicle I expect 'Vehicle.Car.SUV'

Comment: @Chris: Ah, my answer was backward then. I've changed it (and switched to those class names).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I have SUV extending Car extending Vehicle I expect 'Vehicle.Car.SUV'

I'd use `getPrototypeOf` and a loop, starting with the constructor you want to start with, and ending when that constructor's prototype is `Function.prototype` or `null`:

```js
function getLineage(ctor) {
  let name = ctor.name;
  while ((ctor = Object.getPrototypeOf(ctor)) != Function.prototype && ctor) {
    name = ctor.name + "." + name;
  }
  return name;
}

class Vehicle { }
class Car extends Vehicle { }
class SUV extends Car { }

console.log(getLineage(SUV));
```

One suggestion I'd make, though, would be to use a different separator rather than `.`, as `.` seems to suggest that (say) `SUV` is a property of `Car`, which of course it isn't. :-)

Comment: Works perfectly. I chose the . based on typescripts namespace syntax. (They seperate namespaces and class by .